# Proving $(\operatorname{cof} A)^t A = \det A \,I$.

Tags: linear-algebra

**Prove that$\def\cof{\operatorname{cof}}$ $ (\cof A)^tA = (\det A)I$**

$\cof A$ means the cofactor matrix of $A$, and $(\cof A)^t$ means the transpose of cofactor matrix of $A$ (do you call it adjoint of $A$, well I too used to, but no longer). $\det A =$ determinant of $A$ and $I$ is the identity matrix of order compatible with LHS.

The idea I would use is to show that all diagonal elements of $(\cof A)^t A$ is equal to $\det A$ and rest of all the elements are zero.

$i$-th column of $\cof A$ is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
(-1)^{I+1} \det A_{1i} \\
(-1)^{I+2} \det A_{2i}\\
\vdots \\
(-1)^{I+n} \det A_{ni}\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

Therefore, the $I$-th row of $(\cof A)^t = \big[ (-1)^{I+1} \det A_{1i}, (-1)^{I+2} \det A_{2i}, \cdots, (-1)^{I+n} \det A_{ni} \big]$

The $I$-th -- $I$-th element of $(\cof A)^t A$ is
$$
\big[ (-1)^{I+1} \det A_{1i}, (-1)^{I+2} \det A_{2i}, \cdots, (-1)^{I+n} \det A_{ni}\big] \times
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1i}\\
a_{2i}\\
\vdots \\
a_{ni}\\
\end{bmatrix}
 = \sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{I+k} a_{ki} \det A_{ki}$$
Well, the RHS is simply a $\det A$ expanded along the $i$-th column. Therefore, all diagonal elements of $(\cof A)^t A$ is equal to $\det A$.

Now, I would try to prove that all non-diagonal elements are zero. Consider the $I-j$ th element of $(\cof A)^t A$
$$
\big[ (-1)^{I+1} \det A_{1i}, (-1)^{I+2} \det A_{2i}, \cdots, (-1)^{I+n} \det A_{ni}\big] \times
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{1i}\\
a_{2j}\\
\vdots \\
a_{nj}\\
\end{bmatrix}
= \sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{I+j} a_{kj} \det A_{ki}$$

But I'm unable to prove that RHS is equal to zero. Will you help me?

Please keep your answer at introductory linear algebra level, don't use abstract algebra.

Note: My computer in not making me to write small I and so somewhere where there should be a small $I$ we have a big $I$.

Comment: "the RHS is simply a $\det(A)$ expanded along the i-th column" is called a "Laplace expansion"

Comment: Up to sign, your right-hand side is the determinant of a matrix with two equal columns, hence is zero. (You're expanding in cofactors along the $i$th column of $A$, so you have the determinant of the matrix $A$ with its $i$th column replaced with the $j$th column.)

Answer (score -1):

Let $Cof A=C=[c_{pq}]$, then

$[A (Cof A)^t]_{ik}= \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} c^t_{jk}=\sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij} c_{kj}=\det(A) \delta_{ik}$

Comment: This merely reasserts what is to be proved; it does not prove anything.